# Buy X product and get Y another product for free of same category in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

How to implement shopping cart price rules which allow a customer to buy X product of one category and get Y another products of same category for free?

I have followed and implemented the instructions according to the link:

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1733/magento-extension-buy-x-selection-of-products-get-another-y-selection-for-free/

and tried to implement all other ideas. But I am not able to implement it in proper and correct manner.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an observer for the requirement of custom discount.  Please find the files in `https://github.com/alameluvalluvan1/customdiscount`

and follow the instructions.

Comment: I have implemented your observer and followed the instructions that are provided but when i entered the two products of same category priced of 800 and 550,i got the free product of priced 800 in the checkout,but it should be the product which is priced 550.So the code is not working properly according to my implementation

Comment: I think you need the cheapest free. Is it correct?  Please change the code as per requirement.

Comment: In observer i have already marked "Enable Cheapest free" tab as YES.But in that way i am not able to get the cheapest free.

Comment: No You have to modify in the Model/observer.php.  Please sort the for items loop and try this.